# VLC CLI - 2 modes of looping, but only 1 type of parameter

Tags: command-line, bash, vlc-media-player

Any workaround to handle the 2 types of looping in VLC CLI? For whatever reason when I do this command on my mac, it only sets the looping to loop once. I can't get it to infinite loop.

/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --loop "music.mp3"

[image: image of my code]

Comment: Do you mean to ask "why" or "whether"? We cannot answer "why" questions here, only the developer can. Please edit your question to ask what you're actually asking.

Comment: Done. Thank you.